# Infinite Loop When Using pynput to Replace Typed Letters with 'a'

Tags: python, pynput

I'm trying to create a python program to replace every letter typed with an a, but when I try it, it gets stuck in a loop because pyput also listens to the key presses it sends, and it gets stuck in a loop. I also tried to stop the thread before it pressed the key, and restart it after it releases it, but it was too slow.
Here is the code:

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener as KeyboardListener
import pynput.keyboard._win32


keyboard = Controller()


def on_press(key):
    if type(key) == pynput.keyboard._win32.KeyCode:
        keyboard.press(Key.backspace)
        keyboard.release(Key.backspace)
        keyboard.press('a')
        keyboard.release('a')


keyboard_listener = KeyboardListener(on_press=on_press)
keyboard_listener.start()
keyboard_listener.join()
```

Comment: Does this code works? When I run it it froze my IDE and I had to stop execution of python from taskbar after several minutes. (So is the problem it works but is too slow?)

Comment: Not exactly, it does replace the letter you typed with an a, and then replaces the a it just replaced with another a, infinitely, until you stop it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier to use `keyboard`. You can easily detect a key press in a loop that does the desired function:

```
import keyboard

def replace_typed():
    keyboard.press_and_release('backspace')
    keyboard.press_and_release('a')

while True:
    if keyboard.read_key():
        replace_typed()
```

Only downside that I can see here is that it is stuck in a while loop, so if you want to do other functions during the time, you'll need to use `threading` or `multiprocess`, or `asyncio`. At least, it should get rid of the lag problem.

A little advice:

I did find that there is a `keyboard.block_key()` function to block all keys. You can do it like this:

```
import keyboard

for key in range(150):
    keyboard.block_key(key)
```

And it will block all keys. I would recommend being careful with this, because this literally disables your keyboard. You can still do virtual key presses however, and for some reason, `pynput` still detects your keyboard presses even though `keyboard` blocked it. So you won't have to use the pressing of backspace anymore. Now I had a few lag problems with this as well, but something like this is worth a try:

```
import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Listener

for key in range(150):
    keyboard.block_key(key) #blocks all keys

def onPress(key):
    if key.char == 's':
        exit() #fail safe I put in here if everything goes wrong
    
    keyboard.press_and_release('a') #presses a

with Listener(on_press = onPress) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Just a little thing to try, so you don't have to use backspace anymore.

Another update!:

I actually found a suppress argument in `pynput` that would be useful, instead of using backspace again. Here's some code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener

def onPress(key):
    #replace key 'a' here

with Listener(on_press = onPress, suppress=True) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

So hopefully this helps, you'll have to figure out typing the key a though. This does, however, stop the user from actually entering any keyboard input while still detecting key presses.